# Finite Number of Principal Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $R$ be a unique factorization domain and $d$ a nonzero element of $R$. There are only a finite number of distinct principal ideals that contain the ideal $(d)$.

Suppose that $d \neq 0$ is not a unit. Then $d = d_1 ... d_n$ for irreducible/prime elements $d_i$; and suppose that $(d) \subseteq (k)$, where $k \neq 0$ is not a unit either, which means $k=k_1...k_m$ for irreducibles/primes $k_i$. Then $d = kx$ for some $x \neq 0$. If $x$ is a unit, then $dx^{-1} =k$ and therefore $(d)=(k)$, which is very uninteresting. So suppose that $x$ is not a unit, and therefore $x=x_1...x_s$ for irreducibles/primes $x_i$. Then $d=kx$ becomes $d_1...d_n = k_1...k_m x_1 ... x_s$, and $R$ being a UFD entails that $n = m+s$, where $n \in \Bbb{N}$ is fixed.

So, for each $k \in R$ such that $(d) \subseteq (k)$, there exist integers $m,s \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $n=m+s$, and so to count the total number of $k$ satisfying $(d) \subseteq (k)$ is to count a number that is bounded by the total number of ways of writing a fixed positve integer $n$ as the sum of two positive integers, which is finite. Hence, the number of $k$ with $(d) \subseteq (k)$ is finite, and in fact bounded below by $n$ since $(d) \subseteq (d_i)$ for $i=1,...,n$.

How does this sound?

EDIT:

Here is another attempt, although I wasn't exactly able to do what leibnewtz suggested. Starting with $d_1...d_n = k_1...k_nx_1...x_s$, where every element involved in the equation is a prime/irreducible element, we see that every $k_i$ must be an associate of some $d_i$. WLOG, suppose that $k_i$ and $d_i$ are associates, and therefore $k_i = u_i d_i$ for some unit $u_i$. Then $k = k_1 ... k_m = u_1 d_1 .... u_n d_m = (u_1....u_n)d_1...d_m = u d_1 ... d_m$, where $u = u_1...u_m$ is a unit, which means $(k) = (u d_1 ... d_m) = (d_1 ... d_m)$. Thus, for each $k$ satisfying $(d) \subseteq (k)$, $(k)$ is just the ideal generated by some finite product of the $d_i$ with nonrepeating factors, of which there are only finitely many.

How does this sound?

Comment: Is the term "unique factorization ring" the same as "unique factorization domain"?  It sounds like you include noncommutative rings when you say "unique factorization ring."  Maybe it's my ignorance and the term "unique factorization ring" simply includes nonunital rings.  (I saw your tags, but I just wanted to make sure.)

Comment: @Batominovski Sorry. I miscopied the problem; it should be "unique factorization domain."

Comment: OK, then I have one comment.  From your work, you can easily see a flaw if you take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $d=6$.  Then, $n=2$ and the number of ways to write $d$ as a sum of two positive integers is $1$.  So, you should expect that there is only one principal ideal $(k)$ containing $(d)$.  However, $k=1,2,3,6$ works.  I suggest that a good bound is $2^n$, and I leave this bound as a hint for now.

Comment: Try to show that the only principle ideals containing $(d)$ are those whose generator is some unit multiple of $d_{i_1}d_{i_2}...d_{i_k}$, where $i_j \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ and $k \leq n$.

Comment: @leibnewtz Thanks for the hint; I'll give it a try. Just one question: why are you using sub-subscripts on the variable $d$? What's the need for that?

Comment: You're not limited to taking products such as $d_1d_2...d_k$. One could take a product such as $d_3d_5...d_7d_9$, for example.

Comment: @leibnewtz But aren't all of these products equivalent up to units, so that we only need to consider $d_1...d_k$?

Comment: Well one could reorder the product so $d_3$ becomes $d_1$, say, but otherwise no. Consider for example $2*3*5*7$. Then $2*3*5 \neq 2*3*7$.

Comment: @leibnewtz Okay. I wasn't able to do exactly as you suggested, but I came up with a proof based on your suggestion. Perhaps you could take a look at it when you get a chance.

Comment: Why don't you post an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per leibnewt's suggestion, here is what I believe is a solution to the problem:

Suppose that $d \neq 0$ is not a unit. Then $d = d_1 ... d_n$ for irreducible/prime elements $d_i$; and suppose that $(d) \subseteq (k)$, where $k \neq 0$ is not a unit either, which means $k=k_1...k_m$ for irreducibles/primes $k_i$. Then $d = kx$ for some $x \neq 0$. If $x$ is a unit, then $dx^{-1} =k$ and therefore $(d)=(k)$, which is very uninteresting. So suppose that $x$ is not a unit, and therefore $x=x_1...x_s$ for irreducibles/primes $x_i$. Then we have $d_1...d_n = k_1...k_mx_1...x_s$ ($m\leq n$), where every element involved in the equation is a prime/irreducible element, we see that every $k_i$ must be an associate of some $d_i$. WLOG, suppose that $k_i$ and $d_i$ are associates, and therefore $k_i = u_i d_i$ for some unit $u_i$. Then $k = k_1 ... k_m = u_1 d_1 .... u_m d_m = (u_1....u_m)d_1...d_m = u d_1 ... d_m$, where $u = u_1...u_m$ is a unit, which means $(k) = (u d_1 ... d_m) = (d_1 ... d_m)$. Thus, for each $k$ satisfying $(d) \subseteq (k)$, $(k)$ is just the ideal generated by some finite product of the $d_i$ with nonrepeating factors, of which there are only finitely many.

Comment: It’s not that $x$ is unit is uninteresting case, but you have to consider all the cases (including $d$ is unit) to prove $\exists$ finite number of distinct principal ideals that contain $(d)$. Two principle ideal can be equal with different generators, i.e. it is possible to have $(a)=(b)$ where $a\neq b$. I am adding detail of $(k)=(d_1\cdots d_m)$ for future reference. $$(k)=(ud_1\cdots d_m)= ud_1\cdots d_mR=uRd_1\cdots dR=(u)(d_1\cdots d)=R(d_1\cdots d)=(d_1\cdots d).$$